# How to display custom video controls even in fullscreen

Tags: html, video, fullscreen

**Update:** Can't see to get things working in Firefox : (

How can I display custom video controls when the in fullscreen mode in modern browsers?

They disappear as soon as I go fullscreen. I'd like them to be available, and then I'll write some JavaScript to hide them on inactivity and show them once someone wiggles their mouse around.

HTML:

```
<video#video src="vid.mp4" preload poster="/images/poster.jpg">
  <iframe src="https://youtube.com/embed/id" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen>
</video>
```

JS:

```
var bigPlayButton = document.getElementById('big-play-button')
var video = document.getElementById('video')
var playPauseButton = document.getElementById('play-pause')
var fullscreen = document.getElementById('fullscreen')

function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (!document.fullscreenElement) {
      document.documentElement.requestFullscreen()
  } else {
    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen()
    }
  }
}

fullscreen.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  if (!video.classList.contains('fullscreen')) {
    video.requestFullscreen()
  } else {
    document.exitFullscreen()
  }
}, false)

// Detect FullScreen changes and adjust button
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', function (event) {
  if (document.fullscreenElement) {
    fullscreen.children[0].src = '/images/nofullscreen.svg'
    video.classList.add('fullscreen')
  } else {
    fullscreen.children[0].src = '/images/fullscreen.svg'
    video.classList.remove('fullscreen')
  }
}, false)
```

CSS

```
video::-webkit-media-controls {
  display: none !important;
}
#custom-video-controls {
  z-index: 2147483648;
}
```

I'm using this polyfill: https://github.com/neovov/Fullscreen-API-Polyfill

Comment: If you post your code, people at SO might be able to find where the problem is.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## Edit

The significant change was targeting the parent tag: `.vidFrame` for fullscreen instead of the `<video>` tag as per Kaido's comment.

---

HTML5 video's controls need special handling if you want to override them. I'm assuming you want to do that since the controls already have the full screen feature built in the controls. This demo implements:

- `classList` for toggling the `button#fullScreen` states of `.on` and `.off` and `button#playPause` states of `.play` and `.pause`.
- `:fullscreen` pseudo-class to insure `.vidBar` is on the bottom when in full screen mode.
- `Shadow DOM` CSS Styles that are needed to override the native player's controls.
- `Fullscreen API` vendor specific methods to enter and exit full screen mode of course.
- There's no volume slider, mute button, or scrubber, just the full screen button (`button#fullScreen`) and play button (`button#playPause`). If you want them, ask another question.
- Details are commented in source.

It looks as if the Snippet isn't fully functional, so here's a functional [**Plunker**](https://run.plnkr.co/preview/cjnf5ajsc00033b5sl05ic020/). If that version cannot be reached, then review the **[embedded Plunker](https://embed.plnkr.co/WMh7EtqXRDHx6AbvWJ4E/)** and click the full view button:

[image]

---

### Demo

**Note: SO sandbox has changed so this demo is not fully functional go to the links mentioned previously or copy and paste the demo on a text editor.**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Full Screen Video Toggle</title>
<style>
.vidFrame { position: relative; top: 10%; width: 320px; height: auto; min-height: 180px; outline: 1px dashed red; }
.vidBar { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; left: 0; height: 40px; width: 99%; }

#fullScreen { position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; outline: none; border: 1px solid transparent; border-radius: 6px; display: block; cursor: pointer; }

#fullScreen:hover { border: 1px groove #0ef; }
.on, .off { background: url('https://i.imgur.com/0FTwh6M.png') no-repeat; width: 36px; height: 36px; }
.off { background-position: 0 0 }
.on { background-position: -1px -50px }

#playPause { position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0; width: 36px; height: 36px; background: none; font-size: 36px; color: #0ff; line-height: 1; border: 1px solid transparent; display: block; cursor: pointer; outline: none; }
#playPause.play:before { content: '\25b6'; }
#playPause.pause:before { content: '\275a\275a'; }

.vid { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; width: 100%; height: auto; display: block; z-index: 1; outline: 1px dotted blue; }
/* 
Fullscreen Pseudo-class: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen 
*/
.vidBar:-moz-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar:-webkit-full-screen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar:-ms-fullscreen { position: fixed; }
.vidBar:fullscreen { position: fixed; }
/* 
Special Shadow DOM Settings to Override Default Controls: 
https://css-tricks.com/custom-controls-in-html5-video-full-screen/ 
*/
video::-webkit-media-controls-enclosure { display:none !important; }
.vidBar { z-index: 2147483648; }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<figure class="vidFrame">
  <video id="vid1" class="vid" src="http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4"></video>
  <figcaption class="vidBar">
    <button id='playPause' class="play" title="Play/Pause Video"></button>
    <button id='fullScreen' class="on" title="Enter/Exit Full Screen"></button>
  </figcaption>
</figure>
<script>

/* 
Toggle Button with classList: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList 
*/
var fullBtn = document.getElementById('fullScreen');
var playBtn = document.getElementById('playPause');

playBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var player = document.getElementById('vid1');

  if(player.paused) {
    playBtn.classList.remove('play');
    playBtn.classList.add('pause');
    player.play();
  } else {
    playBtn.classList.add('play');
    playBtn.classList.remove('pause');
    player.pause();
  }
}, false);

fullBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
  var tgtEle = document.querySelector('.vidFrame');
  var  onOrOff = fullBtn.classList.contains('on');

  if (onOrOff) {
    enterFS(tgtEle);
    fullBtn.classList.remove('on');
    fullBtn.classList.add('off');
  } else {
    exitFS();
    fullBtn.classList.add('on');
    fullBtn.classList.remove('off');
  }
}, false);

/*
Fullscreen API:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API
*/
function enterFS(element) {
  if (element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
}

function exitFS() {
  if (document.exitFullscreen) {
    document.exitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
    document.msExitFullscreen();
  } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
  }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Rockstar! Thanks for the thorough reply.

Comment: @Costa, you have to call the `enterFS` method on the container element, not on the video one...

Answer (score 7):

## Use the Fullscreen API on the container element, not on the video

As @Kaiido says in the comments:

> You have to call the `enterFS` method on the container element, not on
>   the video one.

So the answer is to use the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API) on the container element rather than the `<video>` element. This enables providing custom controls in that container which is now all in fullscreen.

For reference, that is the existing enterFS() function from the question:

```
function enterFS(element) {
  if (element.requestFullscreen) {
    element.requestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.msRequestFullscreen) {
    element.msRequestFullscreen();
  } else if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    element.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else if (element.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    element.webkitRequestFullscreen();
  }
}
```

---

*I posted this answer because I had to read the page three times to figure out what was going on here.*

*There is great information in @zer00ne's answer that is relevant to others with similar issues, but it doesn't directly answer @Costa's original problem, which was previously only answered in a comment.*