# How do I display my custom HTML video controls (or a div) on top of a full screen video?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, fullscreen

I have been looking for a solution for the past two hours but haven't found one yet. I have these two javascript functions:

```
function fullScreen() {
     if (vid.requestFullScreen) vid.requestFullScreen();
     else if (vid.webkitRequestFullScreen) vid.webkitRequestFullScreen();
...
}
```

and another one for exiting full screen mode.
However I can't seem to exit full screen mode with a double click event listener on my video and no matter what I tried, I wasn't able display my video controls in full screen mode. I have a video and a div (the controls) inside a div called "player_box". When I try raising the z value and change the controls div to absolute it has no perceivable effect on the div.

```
<div id="player_box">
    <video id="my_video">
        <source src="test2.mp4">
    </video>
    <div id="controls_bar">
        <a href="#" title="Play/Pause" class="tooltip"><span title=""><button id="playPause"></button></span></a>
        <input id="seekslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="0" step="1">
        <span id="curtimecode">00:00</span> / <span id="endtimecode">00:00</span>
        <a title="Mute/Unmute" class="tooltip"><span title=""><button id="mutebtn"></button></span></a>
        <input id="soundslider" type="range" min="0" max="100" value="100" step="1">
        <a title="Fullscreen" class="tooltip"><span title=""><button id="fullbtn"></button></span></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Currently I can only interact with the video in "normal mode" I can use event listeners and video controls, but as soon as it becomes full screen there is no way for me to interact with it. I have to either reload the page or press Esc / F11.

Update:
You can use the event listeners in full screen mode I have put in the wrong element, that's why it didn't work. The initial problem remain though.

Comment: Does `vid` contain just the player (the `#my_video` element) or does it contain the player with the custom controls (the `#player_box` element)?

Comment: vid contains the video only. var vid = document.getElementById("my_video");

Comment: @Malik Mr. Beck is correct, here's an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38152812/2813224) of mine, which I just updated,

Answer (score 2):

The [`requestFullScreen()` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/requestFullScreen) can apply to any HTML DOM elements, not just `<video>` tags.

Right now you're setting the video element itself to fullscreen, so that's what shows up full screen.

You want the custom controls to be included, so set the parent element containing both the video and those controls to fullscreen:

```
function fullScreen() {
     var vidContainer = document.getElementById("player_box"); // instead of #my_video
     if (vidContainer.requestFullScreen) vidContainer.requestFullScreen();
     else if (vidContainer.webkitRequestFullScreen) vidContainer.webkitRequestFullScreen();
     // ...
}
```

You do need to set the CSS of the elements contained in the fullscreen node such that they'll actually fill the full screen area (100% width and height, etc.) If necessary, you can use the `:fullscreen` pseudo-class in most browsers to set different styling when in and out of fullscreen mode:

```css
#player_box:fullscreen {position:relative}
#player_box:fullscreen #my_video {width: 100vw; height: 100vh}
#player_box:fullscreen #controls_bar {bottom: 0}
```

(...though now that I look more closely, support for this pseudo class is not complete; some browsers use `:full-screen` instead, and some don't support it at all.  It may be better to toggle a new classname onto the element when triggering fullscreen, and base your fullscreen rules on that instead  -- i.e. have css rules for `#player_box` and for `#player_box.isFullscreen`, and toggle .isFullscreen onto the element when needed.)

Comment: If I do that, it doesn't fill up the entire screen. Well it does, but most of it is just black.

Comment: That's a CSS issue; I updated the answer to show some info on how to correct that.

Comment: I know I've also tried that, but the issue remains. I can't post my css here because it has too many characters. You can find it here https://pastebin.com/GaTuS5Fu

Comment: You appear to be using hardcoded pixel-based sizes for everything.  If you want that to scale to different screen sizes you'll need to switch to relative units (vw/vh, %, etc.)

Comment: That actually worked. Thank you very much! The "controls_bar" is still not being displayed however and the video takes up the entire screen.

Comment: You may need to z-index the control bar above the video (which will work now that the control bar is included in the fullscreen stacking context), and/or adjust the size of the video -- the above was just a very quick example and may not work exactly as is with the other CSS on your page.

Comment: It's not working because the :fullscreen doesn't affect the div. I can change the values and even remove it completely without anything changing. I guess I will have to research :fullscreen now.

Comment: My apologies, that pseudoclass has much less browser support than I thought.  I updated the answer with a different suggestion that should work more consistently.

Comment: Appreciate it. You don't need to apologize you were a great help n finding a solution to my problem.

Comment: I've tried to implement the updated suggestions and it still doesn't work... I will just use the default controls in full screen, because Firefox won't let me use full screen controls...

Comment: @Malik Mr. Beck is correct, here's an [old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38152812/2813224) of mine, which I just updated,